# Why dont my functions work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is python 3, this code basically checks if a word is the same when read backwards. When i execute this through Visual Studio, nothing happens, and I get the prompt to press any key to continue...

```
if "__name__" == "__main__":
    StartProgram() 

def StartProgram():
    Input = AskForDataSimple()
    print(CheckIfPalindrome(Input))

def AskForDataSimple():
    print("Please input the line to test.")
    In = input()
    return In

def CheckIfPalindrome(x):
    if x[::-1] == x:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Please note that this simpler version actually works:

```
x = input()

if x[::-1] == x:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: Don't edit all the suggestions into your code because it renders the answers obsolete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if "__name__" == "__main__":
```

Change this to

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

`__name__` is a variable containing name of this module. You need these line so that your main logic would be used only if this file is executed directly, not when imported as a module by another code.

Still it won't work, because you need to define the function you call before these lines: move these lines to the end of the file.

Also, this

```
def CheckIfPalindrome(x):
    if x[::-1] == x:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

can be replaced with

```
def CheckIfPalindrome(x):
    return x[::-1] == x
```

Comment: and move it to the bottom

Comment: @Tim if you remove the whole first two lines, there would be nothing calling the functions you are defining, don't you think?

Comment: @Tim you should not remove the first 2 lines, otherwise no one will call your function. Move them to the bottom of the file

Comment: Yep, thanks that worked. Coming from C# where the order doesn't matter this is pretty new to me...thanks again!

Comment: @Tim, Python is interpreted line by line. So even order of `import` statements matters

Answer (score 1):

Move main function to bottom of file and try it

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
      StartProgram()
```